# How to display half or a quarter of an ImageView in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an ImageView that I want to show only parts of at a time. But starting from the same x,y coordinates. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you don't find a way using an `ImageView`, it should be quite easy to create your own `view` implementation that does that.

Comment: I tried this, but the image always scales itself down. Is there a way to prevent the image from scaling and just cut off the region that I'm not showing?

Comment: Yes, you can use one of the drawBitmap-methods that allow you to set both a subset of the original image and of the canvas, such as this one:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

If you set the src-rect to a fourth of the source image, and the dst-rect to a fourth of the canvas, you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable ).getBitmap();
bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , startX, startY, width, height);
imgview.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

you can also resise your image

```
Bitmap  resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scrwidth, scrwidth, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

resize picture using x and y

```
top = 0;
bottom = bitmap.getHeight() / 2; //half of picture
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(toBeCropped, 0, top, 
toBeCropped.getWidth(), bottom);
```

2nd half can be resized

```
top = (bitmap.getHeight() / 2);//starting from here (half)
bottom = (bitmap.getHeight() / 2) ;
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(toBeCropped, 0, top, 
toBeCropped.getWidth(), bottom);
```

hope this will help you in some matter